# Livewire pagination component not refreshing parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i dont know how exactly explain this
I have a list paged.. with picture, name, .. and a button that opens a modal.

my first item has this button

```
    <button x-on:click="Livewire.emit('showModal', 40338456744)"><span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-blue-100 text-blue-800">Listo para Envio</span></button>
```

when i go to page 2 for example my first item has this button

```
    <button x-on:click="Livewire.emit('showModal', 40337432127)"><span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-blue-100 text-blue-800">Listo para Envio</span></button>
```

but when i click on the button the showModal function receives again the first id 40338456744.

I dont understand why ?!

```
public function showModal($id = null)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code with this solution

changed

```
    x-on:click="Livewire.emit('showModal', 40337432127)"
```

with

```
    wire:click="$emit('showModal', 40337432127)"
```

and now is working good.. maybe there is any problem with javascript call function. I dont know.